# SSIS - job scheduler error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am using the scheduler to program the execution of a simple package of SSIS (it is a test).

[image]

This is the code I'm using in my .bat file:

```
@echo off 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE "Complete Path\Package 1.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EWCDI 
echo Finishing........
exit
```

The SSIS package is composed by an **OLE Source  -> Conditional split -> OLE Destination**

When I try to execute it I've got the next error:

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL server Data Tool you must install
>   Conditional Split of Integration Services or higher.

By deleting the Conditional Split the problem is resolved. My question is, what to I need to install. or what is missing that is provoking this failure in the execution?

I am using MVS 2010 and SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: `SQL SERVER 2010` ?? It is SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS package runs on client side. If you'd like to execute package on some environment, SSIS should be installed locally on this environment. If integration Service is not installed, you can develop and run packages in Business Intelligence Development Studio, but not as scheduled task. I guess you are trying to schedule package execution on a server where SSIS is not installed.